# How to paste link into html template in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, html-parsing

I am using symfony 3 to input a link into my HTML template, which is saved as a database entry in the table. I can get the html version of the template (by querying for `html_body` from the database) and string version of the link.

Question is: what is the best way to input my link into specific section of my html template.

More general question: how do I insert one html element into specific section of another html element given above input?

I was thinking about using twig variable like `{{ link }}` and then rendering my template and passing link into it as a variable. But I do not have this template file saved anywhere so cannot refer to it as

```
renderView('FrontEnd/emailSubscribe.html.twig', ['link' => $urlButton]));
```

Value of `FrontEnd/emailSubscribe.html.twig` file is saved in the the variable `$templatehtml`, which I query from my DB.

Any assistance with my issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render a Twig template from string.

Assuming you have your template in `$templateBody` and the link in `$urlButton` you can do that like this:

```
$template = $this->get('twig')->createTemplate($templateBody);
$renderedString = $template->render(array('link' => $urlButton));
```

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple. Thanks alot dragoste.